# Using AJAX & JQuery to return a python value from python script

Tags: python, jquery, ajax, flask, web-applications

I am trying to build a simple Tic-Tac-Toe web app. I would like to connect my frontend to my backend logic where I will be running a python script. I believe flask is what I need to use to create a localserver & ajax can be used with jquery to connect button press with python logic. Everything I tried has returned errors or at most I am getting a html page response when I should be getting a json file.

I am very tired and have spent all day trying to figure this out with no success so any help would be greatly appreciated.

My folder structure looks like this:
[folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NS2Hb.png)

***My .js code:***

```
$(document).click(function (e) {
    if ($(e.target).attr("id") == "head") {
        var tossVal = $(e.target).attr('value')
        passCoinToss(tossVal)

        var soundbyte = document.createElement("audio")
        soundbyte.src = "/static/Assets/click1.mp3"
        soundbyte.play()
        remvCoinflip()
    } })


function passCoinToss(Value) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://127.0.0.1:5000//test",
        type: "GET",
        success: function(response){
            alert(response);
        }
    }); }
```

***My python script with flask***

```
# Using flask for simple webhook initialization in order to run our webpage.
from flask import Flask, redirect, url_for, render_template, request, jsonify
from static.Backend.algorithm import coinToss
import os, json

# Declaring the app
app = Flask(__name__)


# Render homepage
@app.route("/")
def main():
    return render_template('index.html')


# Route for CoinToss
@app.route("/test", methods=['GET', "POST"])
@cross_origin()
def test():
    data = {"picked": "1"}
    return json.dumps(data)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    port = int(os.environ.get('PORT', 5000))
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=port, debug=True)
```

Comment: Have you try to add the `contentType: "application/json",` header? on you ajax request

Answer (score 1):

```py
@app.route("/test", methods=['GET', "POST"])
@cross_origin()
def test():
    data = {"picked": "1"}
    return jsonify(data)
```

If you want to return a json data, you can use the jsonify function of flask builtin function.

Comment: Thank you for suggestion I found a solution using jsonify and json.dumps

Answer (score 1):

**SOLUTION**

*Must Json.dumps the data first and then jsonify*

```
# Route for CoinToss
@app.route("/test", methods=['GET', "POST"])
def test():
    data = {"picked": "1"}
    j = json.dumps(data)
    return jsonify(j)
```

*Check to make sure that the url is correct*

```
function passCoinToss(Value) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/test",
        type: "GET",
        contentType: "application/json",
        success: function (response) {
            alert(response);
        }
    });
}
```